# https and Control Panel mixed content error

Tags: ee3, focus-lab-master-config, ssl, secure

I've got a site in SSL but when I visit the Control panel it is completely unstyled and looking in the inspector I see a mixed content error and js/css is being blocked.

Not sure why this is happening, but in case it's relevant am using FocusLab Master Config for EE3

**** **UPDATE** *****

I added this to config.prod.php and no change

```
$env_config['cp_url'] = 'https://www.domain.com/admin.php';
```

**** **UPDATE 2** ****

This is in response to @jrothafer about the config settings. Here is the relevant code from config.master.php

```
$protocol = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$base_url = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$base_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Comment: What's your control panel URL set to in the config?

Comment: Steven:  $env_config['cp_url']   = $env_config['base_url'] . '/admin.php';

Also updated post with additional info

Comment: when you look at the source of the control panel - can you see what's loading over http:// ?

Answer (score 4):

This is always a themes folder and protocol issue, I've found. You mentioned this:

```
$env_config['cp_url'] = $env_config['base_url'] . '/admin.php';
```

What are you parameters for various `$env_config` array entries? Make sure that array is using `https` for that URL, and also your themes folder **must** also be behind SSL.

**Update**

Hey, so are you *forcing* SSL for all connections? If not, you should be! Otherwise,

```
$protocol = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$base_url = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$base_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

This set up will respect the HTTP protocol request and load assets over plain HTTP. You need to force that SSL! Best using `.htaccess` rules, or equivalent nginx rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: See update 2 for additional info.

Comment: Force that https! Edited.

Comment: that's what i do

Comment: jrothafer, I added your htaccess code and this solved part of the issue. but I'm still getting mixed content inside the CP on the publish page when trying to upload images. http://www.domain.com/?ACT=45 is being blocked cause it's not loading on https. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

With help from @jrothafers answer. I hardcoded the themes path in config.master.php and it's working now.

```
$env_config['theme_folder_url'] = https://www.domain.com/themes/';
```

Ideally I wouldn't have to do that, but it works.

Comment: Yay! I updated my answer, but do I win the tacos for my answer?